# Oauth, PHP called by Ajax not redirecting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, oauth

Things are a little bit confusing here.

So I have a button, that activates my AJAX code, this ajax code will call an external php that tries to execute OAuth authentication.

This is my AJAX code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.button').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "ufo.php",
                  data: { action: "authenticate" }
                }).done(function( msg ) {                     
                  var data = JSON.parse(msg);
                  console.log(data);
                  alert(data);
                });    
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, in my php I want to use OAuth to connect to an API. I tested this authentication code and it runs smooth, but when I call it via AJAX I don't get redirected to the API page so I can use the username and password to authenticate.

My php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
switch ($_POST['action']) {
    case 'authenticate':
        authenticate();
    break;  
}
}else{
authenticate();
}

function authenticate(){

$req_url = '...';
$authurl = '...';
$acc_url = '...';
$api_url = '...';
$member_url = '...';
$conskey = '...';
$conssec = '...';

session_start();

if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['state']==1) $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
try {
  $oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
  $oauth->enableDebug();

  if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
    $request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken($req_url, "http://localhost/");
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $request_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
    header('Location: '.$authurl.'?oauth_token='.$request_token_info['oauth_token']);
    $oauth->fetch($member_url, array( "oauth_token" => $request_token_info['oauth_token']));
    exit;
  } else if($_SESSION['state']==1) {
    $oauth->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
    $access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken($acc_url);
    $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
    $_SESSION['token'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
  } 

  $oauth->setToken($_SESSION['token'],$_SESSION['secret']);

  $oauth->fetch("$member_url");
  $member_info = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());
  echo json_encode($member_info);
  die;

} catch(OAuthException $E) {
  var_dump($E);
}
}
```

How can I get my authentication process to run smooth when the php code is called via ajax?

Comment: Page won't change visibly because the redirect will be on what is returned in the ajax call to your success (or done) callback (which you can put into a DIV).

Comment: So that means that I can't do things this way, because I need the redirect to the API page so the process of login can happen. Any idea on how can I do this?